# Magento2: How can call observer function in controller file?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, controllers

I have created a custom observer below:

**Observer file**

```
public function abc($order,$itemIds) {

}
```

**Controller file**

```
public function aaa($order,$itemIds) {
    here we want to call abc($order,$itemIds);
    }
```

Want to call this observer function in custom controller file.
How can do this? Anyone have an idea for that please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observer is a `class` same as any other `class` in Magento and can be initialized via **Dependency Injection** in the constructor or via **ObjectManager** (not preferred).

For Example:

In your

> MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\SaveObserver

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            // Do something
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // silence
        }
    }

   public function abc($order,$itemIds) {
      // Your public function
   }
}
```

In your

> MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Help\Index

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Help;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\SaveObserver;
/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends Action
{
/**
 * ResultPageFactory
 * @var PageFactory
 */
public $resultPageFactory;

public $observer;

/**
 * Index constructor.
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    SaveObserver $observer
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->observer = $observer;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $order = null;
    $itemIds = null;

    $this->observer->abc($order, $itemIds);




return $resultPage;
    }
    }
```

Comment: If that is form different module, not a single module. like an observer from AAA module and controller from BBB module. how call?

Comment: Then too you can call in the same manner via the constructor.
Also, make sure the module is added as a dependency in your `module.xml`.

Comment: This is correct but misleading, for code composition and following the SRP an observer should be calling the logic not containing the logic. Function abc should exist in a third class that both the controller and the observer (the entry points for the logic) call individually.