# Magento 2: How to add a class to an observer without construct

Tags: magento2, event-observer, best-practice

I am making this observer class to check if a visitor is logged in.

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class CheckLoginObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  /**
   * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
   */
  protected $customerSession;

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    //use $customerSession variable here
    ...
  }
```

The goal is to use the $customerSession class in the execute function. What's the right way to do that?

Comment: i am not sure may be help this --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275365/magento2-how-can-call-observer-function-in-controller-file

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Which event are You using for that observer? There is possibility that You can use customer session from Observer. Of course You can check it by look what contain $observer (by using xdebug).
If observer doesnt contain that, You have to use __construct function to load customerSession.

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313448/magento-2-2-6-disk-space-utilization-very-fast